# How convert byte[] into a model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, stream

I'm reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106448/3470178) to upload a file using MVC. I already have the file after a `InputStream.Read` but don't know how use it to create the `IEnumerable<MyModel>` so I can send it to db using EF. The file is a CSV file, I know the structure of.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];
    model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, uploadedFile.Length);

    // now you could pass the byte array to your model and store wherever 
    // you intended to store it

    return Content("Thanks for uploading the file");
}
```

My Model:

```
public class PriceViewModel
{        
    public int PriceId { get; set; }

    public int? YearSelected { get; set; }
    public int? WeekSelected { get; set; }
    public int? StateSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of IEnumerable<MyModel>? You can directly assign byte array in your model stream.

Comment: @AkashKC That is the question. How I do that? The file is a csv, I know the structure so I guess a validation process previous to assign to the model would be nice add to make sure the file have the correct structure

Comment: Can you please share your EF model so that we will know about IEnumerable<MyModel>

Comment: @AkashKC Is Done

Comment: Convert the bytes to string and then parse the CSV into the models. From there you can validate the data and save to database. CsvHelper should help a lot with that

Comment: @Nkosi How I Convert the bytes to string ? I know how parse a string and the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the bytes to string

```
var csv = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uploadedFile);
```

and then parse the CSV into the models.

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) should help a lot with that.

```
var textReader = new StringReader(csv);
var helper = new CsvHelper(textReader);
IEnumerable<PriceViewModel> records = helper.GetRecords<PriceViewModel>();
```

From there you can validate the data and save to database.

Comment: Ok, I try that. But then why on the other question he does `model.File.InputStream.Read`

Comment: They are copying the bytes from the stream into the array

Comment: Ok, I have something on the string. But my text contain spanish words and the accent letters appear with weirds signs instead. Did I damage the data durign the upload or during the conversion?

Comment: But `File` is part of `MyViewModel` isnt an array

Comment: You created the array here `byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];` and then copied the data from teh stream into that array

Comment: Ok, I see. Usually the method affect the objects, but in this case affect the parameters?

Comment: Have to use Encoding.Default to read the accent words. And couldnt use GetRecords() because couldnt match my model so I just read by postion.